# How to play a RTP stream in HTML5?

Tags: rtsp, rtp, http-live-streaming

The Janus server is able to replay the RTP stream.

**Is there a way to play a RTP stream directly into a video html5 element ?**
(I don't really get the difference between RTP and RTSP)

And how can I play the RTP stream: should I transcode it to some HLS ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't, it's not supported in HTML5. I'd recommend transcoding it to DASH and/or HLS, using either open source tools like [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) or commercial solutions like [bitmovin](https://bitmovin.com/encoding-service/).

Answer (score 0):

Webrtc is supported in HTML5, so you can view the video on the browser.

Janus Server supports different plugin for RTSP/RTP, which will receive data in RTSP/RTP and then send that data to the web browser client using webrtc.

https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/streaming.html